# Run shell commands in emacs by something similar to M-x ...?

Tags: commands

I have a program which can run as a command in bash.

Can I run the program in emacs, in some way similar to run emacs' command (i.e.M-x , e.g. M-x occur), instead of first explicitly running a shell in a buffer of emacs and then running the program in the shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

`M-!` runs the command `shell-command`. This will prompt you for the actual command to run in the minibuffer, which then runs. You can run it in the background by putting a `&` at the end, just as you would in a terminal. alternatively, you can use `M-&`, `async-shell-command`.

The output from the shell command will be placed in a temporary buffer. If you want it inserted in the current buffer, use a prefix argument. (i.e., `C-u M-!`.

A very useful related function is `shell-command-on-region`, bound to `M-|` by default. This will run a shell command on the contents of the region. The output will go in a temporary buffer, or, as with `M-!`, if you use a prefix argument the selected region will be replaced by the output of the shell command.

See [(emacs) Single Shell](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs/html_node/emacs_443.html) in the manual for more details.

Comment: @p_wiersig I rejected your edit because I don't fully understand how Compile mode works in this context. With more details, and/or an example, it is probably worth making a separate answer for that!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer, `shell-command` and
`async-shell-command` are the generic way to go.

However, there are also a few tools that can be better in specific contexts.

### counsel-linux-app

This one will give you a completion similar to your DE's start menu,
allowing to start a usually graphical application, provided it has a
configured `*.desktop` file.

Available from the `counsel` package on MELPA and [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper).

### make-it-so

If you have a complicated recipe for transforming a file or a set of
files into other files,
[make-it-so](https://github.com/abo-abo/make-it-so) might be useful
for you. It's on MELPA as well.